# Matplotlib: Plot total number of users over time

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a database with user registrations. For each user, I have the registration date.

I want to plot the total number of users in that date range as a stepped line graph, with the area below the line being filled.

My first idea to plot this was to first create a Numpy array with 0 values for each day in the possible date range, then loop over all the dates and increment the corresponding array item. This can then be plotted using `numpy.cumsum(y)`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

# Get user join dates
User = get_user_model()
datetimes = User.objects.values_list('date_joined', flat=True) \
                        .order_by('date_joined')
dates = map(lambda d: d.date(), datetimes)  # This is now a list of date objects

# Get some auxilliary values
min_date = date2num(dates[0])
max_date = date2num(dates[-1])
days = max_date - min_date + 1

# Initialize X and Y axes
x = np.arange(min_date, max_date + 1)
y = np.zeros(days)

# Iterate over dates, increase registration array
for date in dates:
    index = int(date2num(date) - min_date)
    y[index] += 1

# Plot
plt.plot(x, np.cumsum(y), drawstyle='steps-post')
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image: plot]

My questions regarding this:

- I suspect there is an easier way to achieve what I did, instead of manually filling the x and y axes. Is there an easier way, and if yes, how does it work?
- How can I fill the area below the line with a solid color?
- How can I get dates instead of numbers on the x axis?

Comment: matplotlib will plot against `datetime` objects. `plot(dates, np.cumsum(y))` should 'just work'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I think what you did to get `x`, `y` is fine. `np.cumsum` is the right tool for this job.
- To fill below the plot, check out [fill_between](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html). Fill between the curve and the x-axis.
- To get the dates on the x-axis, just use the `dates` instead of `x`. Or, try using [`plot_date`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date) instead of just `plot`.

Comment: Thanks! Result is here: http://blog.dbrgn.ch/2013/9/26/plot-django-registered-users/